# I'm doing my first small JavaScript project and I'm a bit stuck

Tags: javascript, html

I coded a simple game where you have to guess a random number. The user submits the number and the app compares it to the random generated number. The user gets back a message whether their number is bigger or smaller than the solution.

The Code is :

```js
const start = document.getElementById("start")
const description = document.getElementById("description")
const gameBody = document.getElementById("root")
let valaszokHTML

start.addEventListener("click", gameStart)



function gameStart() {
  gameBody.innerHTML = '<input type = "number"  placeholder ="Enter your guess..." "min="1" max="1000" id="usernumber">' +
    '</input>' + '<button id="guessbutton">This is my guess!</button>'
  const guessSubmit = document.getElementById("guessbutton")
  guessSubmit.addEventListener("click", compareNumbers)
}

function compareNumbers() {
  let userNumber = document.getElementById("usernumber").value

  if (myNumber.szamom > userNumber) {
    gameBody.innerHTML += "<h1>Wrong! It's bigger than " + userNumber


  } else if (myNumber.szamom < userNumber) {
    gameBody.innerHTML += "<h1>Wrong! It's smaller than " + userNumber

  } else if (myNumber.szamom == userNumber) {
    gameBody.innerHTML = "<h1>Right! You won!</h1>"

  }

}



const myNumber = {
  szamom: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="description">
      <h1> Try to guess the number between 1 and 1000!</h1>
    </div>
    <button id="start">Game start</button>
  </div>


  <script src="practice.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So my problem that I can can only click the guessSubmit `button` once. The first time I click it creates the HTML I want, but then I can't use the button anymore. I want it to create a new h1 element whenever I click it (so it will be a bunch of h1 elements below/above each other, until the user gets the number)

Can you please help me and explain, what am I doing wrong?
I would be really appreciate to get some responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a addEventListener at the end of your compareNumbers function, because it is not global.

```js
const start = document.getElementById("start")
const description = document.getElementById("description")
const gameBody = document.getElementById("root")
let valaszokHTML

start.addEventListener("click", gameStart)



function gameStart() {
  gameBody.innerHTML = '<input type = "number"  placeholder ="Enter your guess..." "min="1" max="1000" id="usernumber">' +
    '</input>' + '<button id="guessbutton">This is my guess!</button>'
  let guessSubmit = document.getElementById("guessbutton");
  guessSubmit.addEventListener("click", compareNumbers);
}

function compareNumbers() {
  let userNumber = document.getElementById("usernumber").value

  if (myNumber.szamom > userNumber) {
    gameBody.innerHTML += "<h1>Wrong! It's bigger than " + userNumber


  } else if (myNumber.szamom < userNumber) {
    gameBody.innerHTML += "<h1>Wrong! It's smaller than " + userNumber

  } else if (myNumber.szamom == userNumber) {
    gameBody.innerHTML = "<h1>Right! You won!</h1>"

  }
  let guessSubmit = document.getElementById("guessbutton");
  guessSubmit.addEventListener("click", compareNumbers);
}



const myNumber = {
  szamom: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1,
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="description">
      <h1> Try to guess the number between 1 and 1000!</h1>
    </div>
    <button id="start">Game start</button>
  </div>


  <script src="practice.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

When you do `gameBody.innerHTML += "some text"` you're completely destroying and recreating all the content, hence eventListener of `guessSubmit` will be destroyed too. So maybe add some `<h1 id="answer_text"></h1>` and manipulate it's `innerHtml`